# cabal install pandoc fails for dependency on http-client

Tags: cabal, pandoc

Cabal's version of pandoc is 1.13.1

"cabal update" followed by "cabal install pandoc" yields this message:

setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
http-client >=0.3.2 && <0.4 && ==0.4.6.1

I take this to mean that the version of http-client is too new.

Is http-client 0.4.6.1 known to be too new for pandoc 1.13.1?  If not, how can I change the version required for the cabal build?  (I don't know where the requirement is stated.)

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
cabal install pandoc 'http-client < 0.4'
```

reverted http-client to a 0.3.* version that allowed the build to complete.
See  [pandoc can't install due to http-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534921/pandoc-cant-install-due-to-http-client)